# Create New User Custom Field not Saving

Tags: functions, custom-field, child-theme

I've added a **function** to my child-theme to add a new field in the **Add New User** section so that you can select if the member is either just a member or candidate etc :

```
function show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { 
    $previous_value = '';
    if( is_object($user) && isset($user->ID) ) {
        $previous_value = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'membership', true );
    }
    ?>
<hr>
    <h2>Membership Status</h2>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="membership">Membership</label></th>
            <td>
                <select name="membership" id="membership" style="width:150px;">
                    <option value="Member" <?php selected( 'Member', get_the_author_meta( 'membership', $user->ID ) ); ?>>Member</option>
                    <option value="Candidate" <?php selected( 'Candidate', get_the_author_meta( 'membership', $user->ID ) ); ?>>Candidate</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<hr>
<?php }

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( "user_new_form", "show_extra_profile_fields" );
```

And my **Save Function**:

```
function save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    # save choice
    if( isset($_POST['membership']) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'membership',  $_POST['membership'] );
    }
}

add_action( "user_new_form", "save_extra_profile_fields" );
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
```

My problem is that once I click create it doesn't save my option I've selected in the select box. It does save once I go into the user and then change it again.

What might I have missed that causes the choice not to save on creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hooking your save function to [`user_register`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register), because it could be that the `$user_id` you have in your function doesn't exists yet so there's no user to attach the meta to.

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue. Thanks for assisting me with this.